# can not set dateWindow on click

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I use zoom example https://dygraphs.com/tests/zoom.html
in my project. Everything is working fine, when data inside dygraphs is look like:
"2023//18 09:30,2,6,6.00,0.98,0\n"+
"2023/1/18 09:45,10,4,6.00,0.93,0\n"+
"2023/12/18 09:45:10,10,-4,,,20\n"

But when I use href="http://..." instead ,I have error

"Uncaught referenceError zoomGraphX is not defined"
All other functions works and all series are plotted correctly.